# Magento 2 : How to get Custom Field Image Icon url from admin catalog category page?

Tags: magento2, php-7

Below is my code to display custom field in catalog category form.

> category_form.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="thumbnail" sortOrder="40" formElement="imageUploader">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Category Image Icon</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <required>false</required>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <imageUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="categorylist/category_thumbnailimage/upload"/>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                        <openDialogTitle>Media Gallery</openDialogTitle>
                        <initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>catalog/category</initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>
                        <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>2194304</maxFileSize>
                    </settings>
                </imageUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>

        <!-- <field name="thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Icon Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="categorylist/category_thumbnailimage/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It will save image in Temp folder. Now I want to get that image in phtml file.

In controller file i am already added follow code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {
    protected $baseTmpPath;
    protected $imageUploader;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
    public function execute() {

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
        ];
} catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
}
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

In Setup folder I added InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory) {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        // $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
        //  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image_icon');
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'thumbnail', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Image Icon',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 5,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to display custom image icon url.

How to get?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to define Dataprovider for Image

```
<?php

    namespace VendorName\CategoryBanner\Model\Category;


    use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\EavValidationRules;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo;

    class DataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider
    {
        private $fileInfo;
        protected $_dir;

        public function __construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, EavValidationRules $eavValidationRules, CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, Config $eavConfig, \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir, array $meta = [], array $data = [])
        {
            parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $eavValidationRules, $categoryCollectionFactory, $storeManager, $registry, $eavConfig, $request, $categoryFactory, $meta, $data);
            $this->_dir = $dir;
        }
        private function createImagesDir()
        {
            if ( ! file_exists($this->_dir->getPath('media').'/catalog/category/Banner')) {
                mkdir($this->_dir->getPath('media').'/catalog/category/Banner','0775', true);
            }
        }
        public function getData()
        {
            $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $eavModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');
            $attr = $eavModel->load(134);
            $attributeCode = $eavModel->getAttributeCode();
            $this->createImagesDir();
            $data = parent::getData();
            $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
            if ($category) {
                $categoryData = $category->getData();
                $categoryData = $this->addUseConfigSettings($categoryData);
                $categoryData = $this->filterFields($categoryData);

                $this->loadedData[$category->getId()] = $categoryData;
            }
            $mime = $this->getFileInfo()->getMimeType('/Banner/'.$category->getData('category_banner'));
            $stat = $this->getFileInfo()->getStat('/Banner/'.$category->getData('category_banner'));
            if (isset($data[$category->getId()]['category_banner'])) {
                unset($data[$category->getId()]['category_banner']);

                //create getCategoryThumbUrl in helper file
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $helper     = $objectManager->get('\Shineretrofits\CategoryBanner\Helper\Data');

                $data[$category->getId()]['category_banner'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('category_banner');
                $data[$category->getId()]['category_banner'][0]['url']  = $helper->getCategoryThumbUrl($category);
                $data[$category->getId()]['category_banner'][0]['size'] = isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0;
                $data[$category->getId()]['category_banner'][0]['type'] = $mime;
            }

            return $data;
        }

        protected function getFieldsMap()
        {
            $fields = parent::getFieldsMap();
            $fields['general'][] = 'category_banner'; // NEW FIELD

            return $fields;
        }
        private function getFileInfo()
        {
            if ($this->fileInfo === null) {
                $this->fileInfo = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(FileInfo::class);
            }
            return $this->fileInfo;
        }
    }
```